# Find freshly deployed contracts on ethereum network

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan

Hi folks is there a simple way using which I can find the latest contracts being deployed(for an erc20 token) on the ethereum network, I mean may be etherscan.io or something where I could see that what were the contracts deployed in the last 1 hour/ 1 day etc?

Comment: You can easily chek the latest blocks and find out all contract creation transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure of an easy way to see all recently *deployed* contracts, but depending on your use case, Etherscan does have a way to see recently *verified* contracts. See [here](https://etherscan.io/contractsVerified)

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup your own node, or use the service like Chainstack, and then listen to all txs.

Then you have to develop your own set of filters on contract events like `TokenCreation`, `PairCreated`, `Transfer` (sum of tokens) etc. to identify the token deployments.